# Integration does not give real value

Tags: numerical-integration

The code below must be obvious. We are trying to integrate a complicated function from 0 to 1.

```
a = 180 u^2 - 200 u + 60
b = 30 u^2 - 100 u + 40
c = Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]
Integrate[c, {u, 0, 1}]
```

Mathemtica does not output the real value. Where could i have been possibly wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

That's because, unless you request it otherwise, *Mathematica* will give you *exact* results.

```
a = 180 u^2 - 200 u + 60
b = 30 u^2 - 100 u + 40
c = Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]
Integrate[c, {u, 0, 1}]
```

$\int_0^1 \sqrt{\left(30 u^2-100 u+40\right)^2+\left(180 u^2-200 u+60\right)^2} \, du$

*is* the exact result.

If you want the numeric value, Apply *N* to the result:

```
N@%

(*
27.0188
*)
```

or use *numeric integration*:

```
NIntegrate[c, {u, 0, 1}]

(*
27.0188
*)
```